# Bootstrap 3 btn-group stacking vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create an inline btn-group inside of a column with bootstrap3 classes, but the btn group isn't behaving as expected. Instead of being connected and displayed on the same row, the buttons are being vertically stacked and also appear bigger than they should. Here is a view of what is happening: 
[btn-group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR6Xm.png)

And the html for this part of the page:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Also, no CSS has been applied to the buttons. Any help or suggestions are appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can't get this reproduced: https://jsfiddle.net/od33yvLx/ Could you share more HTML? Maybe there is a `div` outside restricting the width.

Comment: You need to post code that reproduces the problem you are having -> [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

Switch:

```
<div class="btn-group">
```

To:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 .btn {
     float:left;
  }
```